# Read multiple excel files in order from folder with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sorting, concatenation

I have a folder with several excel files in the format xls and xlsx and I am trying to read them and concatenate them in one single Dataframe. The problem that I am facing is that python does not read the files in the folder in the correct order.

My folder contains the following files:
190.xls , 195.xls , 198.xls , 202.xlsx , 220.xlsx and so on

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

my_path = 'my_Dataset/'

xls_files = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f2) for f2 in Path(my_path).rglob('*.xls')], sort = False)

xlsx_files = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f1) for f1 in Path(my_path).rglob('*.xlsx')],sort = False)

all_files = pd.concat([xls_files,xlsx_files],sort = False).reset_index(drop=True))
```

I get what I want but the FILES ARE NOT CONCATENATED IN ORDER AS THEY WERE IN THE FOLDER!!!!!
meaning that in the all_files Dataframe I first have data from 202.xlsx and then from 190.xls

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what if u read the xls_files, append the xlsx files to xls and pd.concat only once? that way, the xls files are surely before xlsx files and ur concat also happens only once, which should count for some efficiency. just a suggestion.

Comment: Instead of `Path(my_path).rglob('*.xls')` use `sorted(Path(my_path).rglob('*.xls'))`

Comment: You can create a loop with order you need first and in that loop do your `pd.concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

my_path = 'my_Dataset/'
all_files = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in sorted(list(Path(my_path).rglob('*.xls')) + list(Path(my_path).rglob('*.xlsx')), key=lambda x: int(x.stem))],sort = False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I have a doubt! What If I have the files in the following order in the folder: 
190.xls , 195.xlsx , 198.xls , 202.xlsx
So what if the file that I want to be the second to be concatenated is in xlsx format thus different from the previous one? Would this code work anyway? Would the 195.xlsx file put after 190xlsx or after 198.xls?

Comment: Try `print(sorted(list(Path(my_path).rglob('*.xls')) + list(Path(my_path).rglob('*.xlsx')), key=lambda x: int(x.stem)))` to check the result

Comment: Great1!! IT WORKKSSS! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Update this

```
all_files = pd.concat([xls_files,xlsx_files],sort = False).reset_index(drop=True))
```

to this

```
all_files = pd.concat([xlsx_files,xls_files],sort = False).reset_index(drop=True))
```